# Only the last entry is selected to itab

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

At my selection Screen you can choose with a radio button Group with which kind of number you want to select the information. (material number,  construction contract or  customer order).

After choosing a kind, the User have to fill in the number(s) into the corresponding select option.
With this information I select the information I need an move them to the itab `t_marc`. This table has the same fields as `marc`.

When the User choose *material number* at the selection screen everything works fine and the values to every number the user wrote down is displayed at the ALV-List.

When selecting by one of the other numbers, the values in output are also right, but only the information to the last denoted number will be edited.

How can I move all numbers to my itabs?

```
PARAMETERS: p_mat RADIOBUTTON GROUP radi.
PARAMETERS: p_auf RADIOBUTTON GROUP radi.
PARAMETERS: p_vbl RADIOBUTTON GROUP radi.

SELECT-OPTIONS: s_matnr FOR   marc-matnr.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_aufnr FOR   aufk-aufnr.
SELECT-OPTIONS: s_vbeln FOR   vbap-vbeln.
```

start-of-selection

```
  IF p_mat = 'X'.
    SELECT * FROM marc
       INTO TABLE t_marc
            WHERE matnr IN s_matnr
              AND werks =  p_werks.

  ELSEIF p_auf = 'X'.
    SELECT * FROM afpo
       INTO TABLE t_afpo
            WHERE aufnr IN s_aufnr.
    LOOP AT t_afpo.
      SELECT * FROM marc
         INTO TABLE t_marc
              WHERE matnr =  t_afpo-matnr
               AND werks  =  p_werks.
    ENDLOOP.

  ELSEIF p_vbl = 'X'.
    SELECT * FROM vbap
       INTO TABLE t_vbap
            WHERE vbeln = s_vbeln-low
              AND posnr IN s_posnr.
    LOOP AT t_vbap.
      SELECT * FROM marc
         INTO TABLE t_marc
              WHERE matnr =  t_vbap-matnr
               AND werks  =  p_werks.
    ENDLOOP.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overwriting the records every time in this loop (and the similar loops).

```
 LOOP AT t_afpo.
  SELECT * FROM marc
     INTO TABLE t_marc
          WHERE matnr =  t_afpo-matnr
           AND werks  =  p_werks.
ENDLOOP.
```

"INTO TABLE" overwrites every time.  You could switch to "APPENDING TABLE."  Alternatively, I would use a for all entries select instead (no loop).

```
  SELECT * FROM marc
    INTO TABLE t_marc
     FOR ALL ENTRIES IN t_afpo
   WHERE matnr =  t_afpo-matnr
     AND werks  =  p_werks.
```

Always make sure there are records in the driver table (in this case, t_afpo) or you will have performance issues.